# how to split a dataframe with equal row numbers without randomization?

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I have a data frame that has 182 elements
and I want to split it into 26 parts with 7 elements each, but in the same order as the original data frame.
I saw the `split()` function, but I read that it splits randomly and I want each 7 elements in sequence to be split. What function can I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where did you read that split is random? That is not true.

The documentation is pretty clear at `?split`...

> `split(x, f, drop = FALSE, ...)`
>
> `split` divides the data in the vector `x` into the groups defined by `f`
>
> ...
>
> `x` vector or data frame containing values to be divided into groups.
>
> `f` a ‘factor’ in the sense that `as.factor(f)` defines the grouping, or a list of such factors in which case their interaction is used for the grouping.
>
> ...

The split is based on the second argument, `f`. The split is as random as `f` is - you can choose a random `f` or whatever non-random `f` you would like. In this case, "*I want to split it into 26 parts with 7 elements each*", we can make a good `f` use `rep`:

```
split(your_data, f = rep(1:26, each = 7))
```

Comment: Ha! I did it but without the each = 7 part and it didnt workout but now it works! Thanks a lotttt

Comment: While the sentiment is appreciated, StackOverflow deprecates [using comments to say "thank you"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258004/should-thank-you-comments-be-flagged?lq=1); if this answer was useful you can upvote it (if you have sufficient reputation), and in any case if it answers your question satisfactorily you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it.